# os.walk isn't showing all the files in the given path

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.walk

I'm trying to make my own backup program but to do so I need to be able to give a directory and be able to get every file that is somewhere deep down in subdirectories to be able to copy them. I tried making a script but it doesn't give me all the files that are in that directory. I used documents as a test and my list with items is 3600 but the amount of files should be 17000. why isn't `os.walk` showing everything?

```
import os
data = []
for mdir, dirs, files in os.walk('C:/Users/Name/Documents'):
    data.append(files)
print(data)
print(len(data))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `data.extend(files)` instead of `data.append(files)`.

`files` is a list of files in a directory. It looks like `["a.txt", "b.html"]` and so on. If you use `append`, you end up with `data` looking like

```py
[..., ["a.txt", "b.html"]]
```

whereas I suspect you're after

```py
[..., "a.txt", "b.html"]
```

Using `extend` will provide the second behaviour.

Comment: using data.extend() does work the way i want it to work. I do see what was going wrong now. i did have all the files but my data list was full of other lists. thanks!